# How to make a cartopy figure become larger?

Tags: python, image, cartopy

I am working with Cartopy and I want to make the image bigger. It has a large legnth but I hope to make the width bigger.
This is the code I have so far. I tried changing the figsize, but it only made the colorbar larger.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
x = ax.contourf(lon,lat,sum_mag_sq, 30, cmap='RdBu_r')
ax.coastlines()
gridlines = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
cbar = plt.colorbar(x, fraction=.046, pad=0.04)
cbar.set_label('Power Spectrum (m$^2$/# frequencies)', labelpad=15, y=.5, rotation=270)
plt.title('Frequency Summed Power Spectrum (2018-2019)', y=1.2)
plt.show(
```

[image: cartopy image]

Answer (score 1):

To get a plot of a map with colorbar you must specify several parameters. Here is a working code that demonstrates how to set values of `figsize` and `colorbar` to obtain better plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
#import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import numpy as np

# make up data for plotting
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = -55, 15, -4, 4
#extent = [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]
width = 4
height = 4
xs = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, width)
ys = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, height)
x2d, y2d = np.meshgrid(xs, ys)
z2d = (x2d+y2d)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))  # set figsize (width, height) here
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ct = ax.contourf(x2d, y2d, z2d, 30, cmap='RdBu_r')

ax.coastlines()
gridlines = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)

# create a colorbar
cbar = plt.colorbar(ct, fraction=.08, pad=0.04, shrink=0.5, aspect=12)
cbar.set_label('Power Spectrum (m$^2$/# frequencies)', labelpad=15, y=.5, rotation=270)

plt.title('Frequency Summed Power Spectrum (2018-2019)', y=1.2)
plt.show()
```

The output plot:

[image]